# Exit bash script if subprocess exits with non-zero code

Tags: node.js, bash

I have this line in a bash script:

```
$ node $(node `dirname $0`/foo.js) "$@"
```

In foo.js, I have

```
if(x){
process.exit(0);
}
else{
process.exit(1);
}
```

I want the bash script to abort / error out, if the process defined by

```
$(node `dirname $0`/foo.js)
```

exits with a non-zero exit code.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

### Update

If you want to capture the exit code of the command substitution, assign the output to a variable. The assignment doesn't change the `$?`, so it still contains the status of the substitution.

```
output=$(node ...)
status=$?
(( status )) && exit 1
```

### Original reply

You can check the exit code with `$?`:

```
node ...
(( $? )) && exit $?
```

Or, you can use it directly in a condition:

```
if ! node ... ; then exit 1 ; fi
```

Or, just tell bash to exit on error:

```
set -e
node ...
```

Use `set +e` to restore the normal behaviour if needed.

Comment: can you edit your answer to include the $(node) instead of just node, I feel like that does make a difference? (at least when reading your answer)

Comment: for example, "if ! $(node foo.js) ; then exit 1 ; fi", is probably totally different than "if ! node ... ; then exit 1 ; fi", I need to capture the stdout from the node foo.js process

Comment: Oh wait, you want to exit if the command substitution fails? Then assign the output to a variable: `output=$(node ...)`, the `$?` then holds the exit status of the command substitution.

Comment: @choroba do you have any idea why we can't use this technic with `local` variables? If I do so `status` is always equal to 0.

Comment: @klefevre: You need to declare the local variable before assigning to it, i.e. `local output; output=$(...)`

Comment: ah yes, thank you. it's a kind of weird behavior tho.

Comment: That's because `local` sets the `$?` itself, overwriting the value returned from the command substitution.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would tackle this problem is to add this line before the full command is run:

```
$(node `dirname $0`/foo.js); rc="$?"; if [ "$rc" -ne 0 ]; then exit; fi
```